# Participation in user tab

Tags: support

How is the [participation](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) measured in the users tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of hidden instructions if you hover with your mouse over what you need know. Hovering over 'participation':

> Users most active on this site in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits).

Comment: When it says votes, votes by the user or for the user?

Comment: @Skippy By the user. It's participation, i.e. user activity, not user popularity (or better said, popularity of user contributions, since this is meta even more so as some might intentionally post two opposing answers for others to vote on). ;)